# why pytorch model gives out of range classes after converting into tflite

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, yolov8

I trained yolov8 and then convert into tflite. After converting the tflite model gives me out of range classes.

Like I am using only 4 classes but tflite model gives my classes like 21,11,9 etc. Can some one tell me why my model behaves like that after convert into tflite.

I converted pretrained model yolov8s.pt into tflite and then test the model. Pretrained Model Also return out of range classes and Also gives wrongs scores. Like 2.32,15.23 etc. Why this is happened even on pretrained model.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eoY0.jpg)